# floating and clickable submenu when hovering menu in minimize sidebar

Tags: css, angular, sidebar

so I'm trying to make my submenus in my sidebar float when I hover the icon menu ( that sun-looking ish pic ) like the picture below in angular. How do I do this when the sidebar and the main page are two different components?
[image: interface that I want]

sidebar.component.html

```
    <div id="sidebarRestaurant">
      <ul class="side-menu pl-0 mt-3">
        <li>
          <a
            aria-expanded="false"
            [routerLink]="['/restaurant-location']"
            [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
            <img class="logo-icon mr-3" src="{{assetPath}}/icons/ic_map.svg" />
            <img class="logo-icon logo-icon-active mr-3" src="/assets/icons/ic_map_active.svg" />
            <div *ngIf="!isToggleSidebar">Restaurant Locations</div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div (click)="foldDropdown()" class="sidemenu-dropdown d-flex align-items-center justify-content-start" [ngClass]="{'sidemenu-background': !isActive}">
            <img class="logo-icon mr-3" src="{{assetPath}}rad-lab/icons/ic_food.svg" />
            <img class="logo-icon logo-icon-active mr-3" src="/assets/icons/ic_food_active.svg" />
            <div *ngIf="!isToggleSidebar">Restaurant Services</div>
            <img [src]="foldSubMenu ? '/assets/icons/ic_checron_down.svg' : '/assets/icons/ic_checron_up.svg'" class="" *ngIf="!isToggleSidebar" class="ml-auto fold-chevron" aria-hidden="true"/>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="!foldSubMenu && !isToggleSidebar" class="submenu">
            <div *ngFor="let menu of menuRestaurant">
              <a
                aria-expanded="false"
                [routerLink]="[menu.link]"
                [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
                <div>{{ menu['name'] }}</div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

sidebar.component.css

```
.side-menu {
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 14px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .side-menu li {
      list-style: none;
    }
    
    .side-menu li a, .sidemenu-dropdown {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        color: var(--dark);
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    
    .side-menu li > a, .sidemenu-dropdown {
        padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .side-menu li a:hover, .side-menu li a.active{
      background: rgba(87, 95, 207, 0.08);
      border-right: 6px solid #575FCF;
        color: #575FCF;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .sidemenu-dropdown:hover, .sidemenu-background {
      background: rgba(87, 95, 207, 0.08);
      color: #575FCF;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .border-sidemenu {
      border-right: 6px solid #575FCF;
    }
    
    .fold-chevron {
        transition: all ease 0.5s;
    }
    
    .side-menu li a .logo-icon {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .submenu {
      margin-left: 37px;
    }
    
    .submenu div {
      font-weight: normal;
      padding: 3px 3px 3px 5px;
    }
    
    .side-menu li a .logo-icon-active,
    .sidemenu-dropdown .logo-icon-active {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .side-menu li a.active .logo-icon,
    .side-menu li a:hover .logo-icon,
    .sidemenu-dropdown:hover .logo-icon,
    .sidemenu-background .logo-icon {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .side-menu li a.active .logo-icon.logo-icon-active,
    .side-menu li a:hover .logo-icon.logo-icon-active,
    .sidemenu-dropdown:hover .logo-icon-active,
    .sidemenu-background .logo-icon-active {
      display: block;
    }
```

sidebar.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { MenuRestaurant } from '../../../variables/common.variable';
    import { environment } from '../../../../environments/environment';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-section-sidebar',
      templateUrl: './section-sidebar.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./section-sidebar.component.css']
    })
    export class SectionSidebarComponent implements OnInit {
      @Input() isToggleSidebar = true;
      public assetPath = environment.ASSET_PATH;
      public foldSubMenu = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`foldSubMenu `) || 'false');
      
      public isActive = true;
    
      constructor() {}
    
      public menuRestaurant = MenuRestaurant;
    
      ngOnInit() {
        if (this.menuRestaurant.findIndex((val: any) => val.link === window.location.pathname) >= 0) {
          this.isActive = false;
          this.foldSubMenu = false;
        }
      }
    
      foldDropdown() {
        this.foldSubMenu = !this.foldSubMenu;
        localStorage.setItem(`foldSubMenu `, this.foldSubMenu );
      }
    }
```

page-restauran.component.html

```
<div>
      <section id="sidebar" [ngClass]="isToggle ? 'hide-sidebar' : ''">
        <app-section-sidebar [isToggleSidebar]="isToggle"></app-section-sidebar>
      </section>
      <div>
        <img (click)="minMaxSidebar()" class="toggle-icon" [ngClass]="isToggle ? 'min-toggle' : ''" [src]="isToggle ? assetPath + 'icons/state-left.svg' :  assetPath + 'icons/state-right.svg'" />
      </div>
      <section id="content">
        <app-section-header></app-section-header>
        <main>
                <div class="box bg-white">
                    <app-widget-restaurant></app-widget-restaurant>
                </div>
            </main>
        </section>
    </div>
```

page-restaurant.component.css

```
#sidebar {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 217px;
        height: 100%;
        background: white;
        z-index: 1000;
        transition: .3s ease;
        overflow-x: hidden;
      border-right: 1px solid #DBDDDE;
    }
    
    #sidebar.hide-sidebar {
      width: 50px;
    }
    
    #content {
        position: relative;
        width: calc(100% - 217px);
        left: 217px;
        transition: .3s ease;
    }
    
    #sidebar.hide-sidebar ~ #content {
        width: calc(100% - 50px);
        left: 50px;
    }
    
    #content main {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 36px 24px;
        font-family: var(--poppins);
        max-height: calc(100vh - 56px);
    }
    
    .toggle-icon {
      position: fixed;
      top: 28px;
      left: 205px;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      z-index: 1000;
      transition: .3s ease;
    }
    
    .min-toggle {
      position: fixed;
      top: 28px;
      left: 38px;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      z-index: 1000;
      transition: .3s ease;
    }
```